# How to join a many to many field in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, join

I have no previous experience with many to many fields in Django. This is the first time I´m using it, so I´m getting a little confused here. This is what I have:

```
#models.py
class RefereciaCita(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, help_text='título da pesquisa')
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='link da pesquisa')
    #pesquisador = models.ForeignKey('AutorPesquisa',null=True, blank=True, 
            #help_text='pesquisadores que participam da pesquisa', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    pesq = models.ManyToManyField('AutoresPesq', related_name='autoresDaPesquisa',through='AutorRef', verbose_name='pesquisador')       
    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
    class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Referência bibliográfica"
            verbose_name_plural = "Referências bibliográficas"


class AutoresPesq(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, help_text='nome do pesquisador')
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='link do currículo do pesquisador')
    pesquisa = models.ManyToManyField('RefereciaCita', through='AutorRef', verbose_name='pesquisador',
        related_name='pesquisaDoAutor', help_text='pesquisa que o autor participa')

def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Autores Pesquisa"
        verbose_name_plural = "Autores Pesquisa"

class AutorRef(models.Model):
    pesquisa = models.ForeignKey(RefereciaCita, null=True, related_name='pesquisarn',
            help_text='pesquisa que o autor participa', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pesquisador = models.ForeignKey(AutoresPesq, null=True, related_name='autorDaPesquisa',
        help_text='pesquisadores que participam da pesquisa', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.pesquisador.nome + ", " + self.pesquisa.titulo[:190]

class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Autor Pesquisa"
        verbose_name_plural = "Autor Pesquisa"
```

I need to retrieve, from each ReferenciaCita it's respective(s) AutoresPesq

So in the template I would have something like the picture

[image]

So, I need to get for each 'researchPaper' it´s 'author'

But I'm getting confused with the querysets. I've already tried with select_related and prefetch_related, but I'm missing something here.

The middle table goes like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can do:

```
qs_referencia_cita = ReferenciaCita.objects.all() # All ReferenciaCita

for referencia_cita in qs_referencia_cita:
    for autores_pesq in referencia_cita.pesq.all():
        # Use your autores_pesq
```

The rest is unclear what's you're asking.

PS: You don't need both relations as `ManyToManyField`: The other relation is created automatically, see [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) of the doc.

Comment: yes, thanks for the help... I´ve did like your example, but returned the following `'RefereciaCita' object has no attribute 'autorespesq_set'`

Comment: `for rf in referencias:
        for au in rf.autorespesq_set.all():
            print(au)`

Comment: Edited my answer, I didn't see you had two m2m relation, that is not needed. You can use ` rf.pesq.all()` in your case, `rf.pesq` is an object manager.

Comment: Yes,@Cyrlop, that worked ... thanks a lot for your help... I was really confused about this, because I´ve never used this feature before.... thanks again!

Comment: Glad it fixed your problem, feel free to accept the answer if this particular issue is solved.